# Associative json array with curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I need to send this array:

```
$nums = [
            [
                'title' => 'How to create a simple module',
                'summary' => 'The summary',
                'description' => 'The description',
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'status' => 1
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Create a module with custom database table',
                'summary' => 'The summary',
                'description' => 'The description',
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'status' => 1
            ]
        ];
```

by JSON using curl
I try this one:

```
{"nums":
        {
                {
                 "title":"How to create a simple module",
                 "summary":"The summary",
                 "description":"The description",
                 "created_at":"2016-10-16 12:51:26",
                 "status":1
                },
                {
                 "title":"How to create a simple module",
                 "summary":"The summary",
                 "description":"The description",
                 "created_at":"2016-10-16 12:51:26",
                 "status":1
                }
        }
}
```

but I get an decoding error.

When I send just

```
{"nums":
            {
                    {
                     "title":"How to create a simple module",
                     "summary":"The summary",
                     "description":"The description",
                     "created_at":"2016-10-16 12:51:26",
                     "status":1
                    }
            }
    }
```

It works, and I got

```
Array(
[title] => How to create a simple module
[summary] => The summary
[description] => The description
[created_at] => 2016-10-16 12:51:26
[status] => 1)
```

But it's not what I need.

As I understood, I cant use '[]' brackets when send JSON array by curl, because when I'm trying send

```
{"nums":
    [
            {
             "title":"How to create a simple module",
             "summary":"The summary",
             "description":"The description",
             "created_at":"2016-10-16 12:51:26",
             "status":1
            },
            {
             "title":"How to create a simple module",
             "summary":"The summary",
             "description":"The description",
             "created_at":"2016-10-16 12:51:26",
             "status":1
            }
    ]}
```

I've got exception:

```
Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-58037ddbaccd0; Message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php on line 505 in /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magen$
Stack trace:
#0 /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
#1 /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(219): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
#2 /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 {main} [] []
```

Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON array items must be enclosed by square brakets

```
{"nums":
            [
                    {
                     "title":"How to create a simple module",
                     "summary":"The summary",
                     "description":"The description",
                     "created_at":"2016-10-16 12:51:26",
                     "status":1
                    },
                    {
                     "title":"How to create a simple module",
                     "summary":"The summary",
                     "description":"The description",
                     "created_at":"2016-10-16 12:51:26",
                     "status":1
                    }
            ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> As i understood, i cant use '[]' brackets when send JSON array by curl.

Wherever you got that understanding from, it's wrong. See http://json.org. `[]` are exactly what you need to define the value of `nums` in the JSON, which should look like this:

```
{"nums":
        [
                {
                 "title":"How to create a simple module",
                 "summary":"The summary",
                 "description":"The description",
                 "created_at":"2016-10-16 12:51:26",
                 "status":1
                },
                {
                 "title":"How to create a simple module",
                 "summary":"The summary",
                 "description":"The description",
                 "created_at":"2016-10-16 12:51:26",
                 "status":1
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: {"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-58037ddbaccd0"}

Comment: {"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-58037ddbaccd0"}
Than's i've got when trying do it with '[]' brackets. Log: 
Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-58037ddbaccd0; Message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php on line 505

Comment: @IlliaArefyev: Can't help you with Magento. Can only tell you the above is A) Valid JSON, and B) The correct way to represent an object with a `nums` property that's an array of objects.